# how to let compiler warning about array of objects vs array of instances

Tags: typescript

I want to write some mock data in forms of array of objects.

However I would like to manage the data in instances of classes.

So I want to let typescript to warning about this.

But it doesn't work.

```
class Article {
  title: string;
  userId: string;

  constructor(title: string, userId: string) {
    this.title = title;
    this.userId = userId;
  }
}

const getTitles = (articles: Article[]) => articles.map(article => article.title)

const data = [{title: 'hello world', userId: '1'}];

getTitles(data);
```

Why can I pass array of objects?

I want to let ts warning about this

Answer (score 2):

Typescript uses [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), which means that two types are considered equal if they have the same properties, or the same shape if you want.

In you example, `getTitltes` is expecting an array of `Article`s, which is equivalent to an array of values with a `title` property of type `string` and a `userId` property of type `string`, so the compiler is perfectly happy with your function call.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer, this is because Typescript has a [structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) as opposed to a nominal type system.

One way to make a class type behave more like a nominal type is to give it a special `__brand` property whose type is the class. To avoid any runtime cost, the property doesn't need to really exist; we can just make Typescript think it exists by declaring it, and using `@ts-ignore` to suppress the error about it not being initialised.

This way, the object literal won't have a `__brand` property so you will get a warning; you'll never add a `__brand` property to an object literal by accident, and if you did it would need to be of type `Article` anyway.

```
class Article {
  //@ts-ignore
  private readonly __brand: Article;

  title: string;
  userId: string;

  constructor(title: string, userId: string) {
    this.title = title;
    this.userId = userId;
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=48&pln=3&pc=36#code/MYGwhgzhAECCBOAXAlqAptA3gKGtA9PgAKIQC0yA5gHYD28au0ADvMgG5iIYNgAmtaiACe0APpiARvDDU+ALjhJUINAG5sTFIlWKIiNtUoa8AVwhp4ASQXR9h45rzBB908ET0AFNt12DyEYANNDmljZ6AUYAlFhMeIgAFsgQAHS+GAC80BkmeDnJaWHWfNDZxTZ5AL7YNdgu1PrQlGiIACrIOmgw2V5gyugQiggo6ADaALqxmQB80P2jqmkAtmDMfQOqZXMLKmjpnarRmg1NfFxgZdBjmBmKAOSJaCAgtNAA7vQgfPchFbb3ACM9yqEw02Ba7UO3S850QYGiGiAA)